# Angularjs. undefined is not a function caused by "track by" statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have an array of dates, and have to show them in a select tag

---

> view:

---

```html
<select id="select" name="select" class="form-control"  
        ng-model="files.options.fechaIngreso"  
        ng-change="files.fechaIngresoChanged()"   
        ng-options="date.item for date in files.dates track by date.id">

</select>
```

> ***controller:***

```js
var self = this, data = 4;
self.dates = [];

for (var i =data; i >= 0; i--) {
var historicalDate = moment().subtract(i, 'days').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
var obj = {
     item: historicalDate,
     id: i
};
self.dates.push( obj );
}
```

---

> and got this error:

---

```js
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at render (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular/angular.js:26098:24)
at Scope.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular/angular.js:14358:36)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular/angular.js:14505:26
at completeOutstandingRequest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular/angular.js:4924:10)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular/angular.js:5312:7
```

> Execution fall when is accessing .prop('selected', option.selected)

(file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular/angular.js:26098:24)

```js
 (element = optionTemplate.clone())
.val(option.id)
.prop('selected', option.selected)
.attr('selected', option.selected)
.prop('label', option.label)
.text(option.label);
```

> this case also didn't works

```html
<select id="select" name="select" class="form-control"  
            ng-model="files.options.fechaIngreso"  
            ng-change="files.fechaIngresoChanged()"   
            ng-options="date for date in files.dates track by date">

    </select>
```

```js
var self = this, data = 4;
self.dates = [];

for (var i = data; i >= 0; i--) {
    var historicalDate = moment().subtract(i, 'days').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    self.dates.push( historicalDate );
}
```

have the same error

Comment: format should be: item as item.label for item in items track by item.id

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not the best practice solution but a practical one

```html
<option ng-repeat="date in files.dates" ng-selected="date == files.options.fechaIngreso" value="{{date}}">{{date}}</option>
```